# Is there syntax to assign biggest value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, limit

In the case of python, there is an 'inf' number but I don't find a similar thing in MySQL. And my columns have the 'Not Null' property and I have to put some number in it. So, for the 'inf', I want to assign the biggest possible value allowed by MySQL.  But the max limit is not the same for the different data types. It's quite a hassle to do it for each data type.

Is there any unified way to insert the biggest value automatically for any numeric data types? Or is there any better way to assign 'inf' value into MySQL?

The only goal of the 'inf' number is to compare the values with other values for size in the same column. So, it's ok as long as the 'inf' value is bigger than the other numbers of the same column.

Comment: There is no such function. You'll have to use hard coded values from the documentation, eg [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: If you need nulls on a particular column, remove the not null constraint.